# Xamarin - Error IDE1100 Error reading content of source file

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I've made a new content page, but forgot to type the name.. So I deleted it an made it again with proper name..

I have done it like this multiple times already, but this time something went wrong and I cannot compile. 
I have this error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1100 Error reading content of source file 
'C:\Users\shark\source\repos\GalShare\GalShare\GalShare\Views\Page1.xaml' -- 'Could not find file 
'C:\Users\shark\source\repos\GalShare\GalShare\GalShare\Views\Page1.xaml'.'.    GalShare-XamlProject     
C:\Users\shark\source\repos\GalShare\GalShare\GalShare\Views\Page1.xaml 1   Active
```

I have done nothing except the steps above.. What is the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Cleaning the project did not solve, but closing and reopening solved my problem.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to the answers of *E.Zhao* and *messyprogrames*, here a step-by-step walkthrough.

**Clean Solution:**
Navigation Bar > "Build" > "Clean Solution"

[image]

**Unload project:**
Choose your "problem project" on the right side within the solution explorer. Right mouse click > "Unload Project"

[image]

**Reload project:**
Choose your unloaded "problem project" again. Right mouse click > "Reload Project".

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this did not help me at all

Answer (score 9):

Opening and closing the solution wasn't helping, but unloading and reloading the project worked.

Comment: I had the same experience.  Deleting the obj folder, closing and re-opening visual studio did not help, but cleaning the solution then unloading and reloading the problem project fixed it.  Side note: I'm working in a .NET Framework project, not a Xamarin project, but the problem appears to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it is unnecessary to exit and reopen current solution, try to clean the error project, unload and then reload it again. hope it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out if you get this issue and you have changed to using Project References.

Stackoverflow Approved Graphics:

[image]

So changing App to have a Project Reference to Lib A will cause problems if you have another Library B that uses a NuGet Reference to the same Lib A.

You have to change the Nuget ref back to be a Project Reference as well.

Answer (score 2):

In VS click your initials > Account Settings > and check there's no warning there asking you to re-fresh your credentials. It was this for me. After I re-entered my credentials, cleaned and rebuilt all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unloading and reloading the project worked for me.

To reproduce this, in a new folder add a WPF user control with a accidental typo.

Rename with F2 or simply rename,
the code behind doesn't rename, so change that.
Initalize component gets a good old red squiggly!

create a new one with an appended number as you want to crack on...
delete the user control that you originally created.

You will get this error (well I did on enterprise edition Version 16.7.2)

Then as other contributors have suggest, remove the pain by unloading and reloading the project.