# IDE 1100 Error, I looked up this and only got something not related MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, ide, visual-studio-2022

So I am wondering how come my IDE1100 is not working. I went to the only question related to this and it was about xamarin, [Other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008105/xamarin-error-ide1100error-reading-content-of-source-file?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C56.0970), I am not working with xamarin at all. I clicked on the error for more help it said I don't have F1 button workign but it was working then the issues said I didn't have the RazorAssembly.cs or Assembly.cs files were missing. Okay so I did what they told me to do n the link above but unloading and reloading that also did nothing for me. I then ran clean build again then ran a code analysis on the solution and I got all these weird code naming violations and I did not have the originally. It all started from trying to create a new migration because I was changing variable names. I figured well I don't need the database only one person in it and then bam just like that the issue reappeared. I have no clue of what I done to actually create this error. I don't want to restart the whole project again. I am using VS 2022 with MVC project.

Comment: I try adding the migration it gets a build fail but doesn't give me the reason why it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that it was me that messed up but it would not show my errors at all when I tried to build. [image: Picture]
so I clicked on where my mouse is at in the picture and just clicked on  the plus sign. It was initially build + intelisense but when I clicked build only it actually showed me an error that was easy to fix. I had to change the view names because I changed them. usually it would show me this error even in build + intelisense this never happened before like wth and you see the name stuff is gone too this is baffeling is this actually normal with vs 2022.

Comment: For me it was needing to re-enter my credentials in VS. Click your initials > Account Settings > and check there's no warning there asking you to re-fresh your credentials.  After I re-entered my credentials, cleaned and rebuilt all was fine. Commenting in case it's this for anyone down the line too.